# How to query and index the datasets located in a server using IBM Watson Discovery?

Tags: watson-discovery

I have few documents available in a unix server. Using IBM Watson Discovery how can I connect to the server Location and index those datasets to search and query them

Answer (score 0):

The open source tool [Discovery Files](https://github.com/IBM/discovery-files) can be used to upload files from your Unix machine to Discovery.

I hope [Discovery Files](https://github.com/IBM/discovery-files) works for you! Please let me know if you have any troubles using it.

Comment: Thank you for the information Adams. I would like to put my question more clear " Is it possible to index the and rank the datasets directly from server rather thank adding them to Discovery collections"

Comment: I'm not sure what you have in mind. There is no way for Discovery to reach out across the public internet to grab files from your server, anymore than anyone else on the internet can access files on your server.